# Bounding Co-ordinates of Polygons

Tags: mapinfo, mapbasic

I have created 250 square meter grids using the Grid Maker tool.
I have given each grid a unique name.
I want to find and store bounding co-ordinates (Latitude and Longitude) of each polygon in the Grid table along with the unique grid name.
In short, I want to extract values that are displayed when you select "Get Info" upon Right-Click of any polygon.
Please check screenshots for reference.
I'm using MapInfo 15.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add 4 `float` columns to your table titled something like `X1, Y1, X2, Y2`. Then using `Table` > `Update Column` enter the following:

- Update table: `YourTable`
- Column to update: `X1`
- Get value from table: `YourTable`
- Value: `ObjectGeography(obj, 1)`

Click OK. This will update the X1 column with the minimum X value.

For `Y1` change the column to update to `Y1` and the Value to `ObjectGeography(obj, 2)` for the minimum Y value.

`X2` will be `ObjectGeography(obj, 3)` and is the maximum X value, and finally `Y2` will be `ObjectGeography(obj, 4)` for the maximum Y value.

Comment: Beat me by 3 minutes. Page 493 of [this document](http://reference1.mapinfo.com/software/mapbasic/english/15.0/MapBasicReference.pdf).

Comment: @T_Bacon
Thank you so much for your help!
This worked in seconds!

Answer (score 2):

And if you prefer a statement for your MapBasic window:

```
Set CoordSys Table MYTABLE
Update MYTABLE 
   Set MIN_X = ObjectGeography(OBJ, 1)
     , MIN_Y = ObjectGeography(OBJ, 2)
     , MAX_X = ObjectGeography(OBJ, 3)
     , MAX_Y = ObjectGeography(OBJ, 4)
```

The first statement asks MapInfo Pro to use the coordinate system of the table when extracting coordinates.

The second does the actual update of the four columns.